# Flask route with URI encoded component

Tags: python, flask

It seems Flask doesn't support routes with a URI encoded component.  I'm curious if I'm doing something wrong, or if there is a special flag I need to include.

My route looks something like this:

```
@app.route('/foo/<encoded>/bar/')
def foo(encoded):
  # ...
  pass
```

The URL that this should match can look like these:

```
http://foobar.com/foo/xxx/bar/ # matched correctly, no URI component
http://foobar.com/foo/x%2Fx%2Fx%2F/bar/ # not matched correctly, URI component
```

Former URL works, latter spits out a lovely 404.

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add `path` to your url rule:

`@app.route('/foo/<path:encoded>/bar/')`

Update per comment: The route API docs are here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.route. The underlying classes that implement the `path` style route converter are here: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#custom-converters (this is one of the really nice parts of pocoostan.) As far as the trailing slashes, there are special rules that amount to:

> If a rule ends with a slash and is requested without a slash by the
>   user, the user is automatically redirected to the same page with a
>   trailing slash attached.
>
> If a rule does not end with a trailing slash and the user request the
>   page with a trailing slash, a 404 not found is raised.

Also keep in mind that if you are on Apache and are expecting a slash-trailed url, ie a bookmarklet that submits to `http://ex.com/foo/<path:encoded>/bar` and `encoded` gets something with double slashes, Apache will convert multiple slashes to a single one.

Comment: In case anyone else has the same issue: it took me a minute to realize we were adding `path`, not adding `encoded`. I tried and failed to add an `encoded` post-filter rather than a `path` pre-filter.

Comment: you and I both!